# How do you set background image as background-size: contain on initial load but prevent it from resizing on window resize?

Tags: css

Is there any way to do this? I am creating an HTML app and I do not want the background image to resize when the soft keyboard is opened. Thanks!

Comment: yes this is possible. please show your code/jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

---

```
.element{
    /*important*/
    width: [you-width];
    height: [you-height];
    /*image*/
    background-image: url(some.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    /*optional*/
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

you cans use JS .. when you trigger the display of the keyboard. you add a class on that element and put a fixed value for the BG

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I solved it like this:

```
$scope.getImageSize = function(div){
var backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.src = $(div).css('background-image').replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");

backgroundImage.onload = function() {
    var width = this.width;
    var height = this.height;

    var object = $(div);

    /* Step 1 - Get the ratio of the div + the image */
    var imageRatio = width/height;
    var coverRatio = object.outerWidth()/object.outerHeight();

    /* Step 2 - Work out which ratio is greater */
    if (imageRatio >= coverRatio) {
        /* The Height is our constant */
        var coverHeight = object.outerHeight();
        var scale = (coverHeight / height);
        var coverWidth = width * scale;
    } else {
        /* The Width is our constant */
        var coverWidth = object.outerWidth();
        var scale = (coverWidth / width);
        var coverHeight = height * scale;
    }
    var cover = coverWidth + 'px ' + coverHeight + 'px';
    $localStorage.image = {width: coverWidth + "px", height: coverHeight + "px"};
    $('.pane').css('backgroundSize', $localStorage.image.width + " " + $localStorage.image.height);
    return $localStorage.image;
};

}
```

Since it's a mobile app and I'm locking the orientation I'm assuming the width and height won't change, I change the `background-size` to be equal to the resized width and height from `background-size: contain`.